# Can't access the namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Evaluation in VS 2022 extension project

Tags: c#, vs-extensibility

So I am making an extension for Visual Studio 2022. I want to access the namespace [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.debugger.evaluation?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) in my project (A VSIX project). But when i type this line of code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Evaluation;
```

My IDE will show a red line under it telling me that it can't find the namespace. Does this namespace exist for Visual Studio 2022? Do I need to install something? Was it renamed?

Comment: Don't you need to add a Reference to this assembly ?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Engine